# SelectInputUpdate in R? SelectInput in two tabs that are related

Tags: r, shiny

New code example below where I'm trying to link selectInput in all three tabs.  In the example below, the first two tabs selectInputs are linked but I'm trying to get all three linked. Is there any way to have all three linked?

```````````````````````````````````````
#``````````````````````````````````````
a <- list("2016", "MALE", "25", "50")
b <- list("2017", "FEMALE", "5", "100")
c <- list("2017", "MALE", "15", "75")
d <- list("2016", "MALE", "10", "35")
e <- list("2017", "FEMALE","55", "20")

data <- rbind(a,b,c,d,e)

#``````````````````````````````````````
## UI

library(shiny)

if(interactive()){

  ui = fluidPage(

navbarPage("",

           #``````````````````````````````````````
           ## SHOES TAB

           tabPanel("SHOES", 

                    fluidRow(

                      column(2, "",
                             selectInput("shoes_year", "YEAR", choices = c("2017", "2016", "2015", "2014"))),


                      column(9, "SHOES"))),


           #``````````````````````````````````````
           ## HATS

           tabPanel("HATS",

                    fluidRow(

                      column(2, "",
                             selectInput("hats_year", "YEAR", choices = c("2017", "2016", "2015", "2014"))),

                      column(9, "HATS"))),

  #``````````````````````````````````````
  ## COATS

  tabPanel("COATS",
           fluidRow(
             column(2, "",
                    selectInput("coats_year", "YEAR", choices = c("2017",     "2016", "2015", "2014"))),

         column(9, "COATS")))

))

  #``````````````````````````````````````

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input[["shoes_year"]],
                 {
                   updateSelectInput(session = session,
                                     inputId = "hats_year",
                                     selected = input[["shoes_year"]])
                 })

    observeEvent(input[["hats_year"]],
                 {
                   updateSelectInput(session = session,
                                     inputId = "shoes_year",
                                     selected = input[["hats_year"]])
                 })

  }

  #``````````````````````````````````````


  shinyApp(ui, server)
}

#``````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Do you want to reuse the same input or have two similar inputs that always match?  If you want to reuse it, take it out of the tab panels and place it where it can appear for both rows (like make a whole row of inputs).  If the inputs MUST stay with the tab panels, then you may need two update input select calls AND you'll need to give them different names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things to take note of:

1. Your `inputId`s must be unique.  You can't have two `selectInput` calls with the same `inputId` on two different tabs.  It won't cast an error, but your app won't work the way you want.
2. You will need to include the `session` argument in your server function.
3. Having controls that perform the same task on two different tabs is somewhat redundant.  You may want to consider if having a sidebar (`sidebarLayout`) would work to your advantage.

In any case, the code below works for updating the year selections.

```````````````````````````````````````
a <- list("2016", "MALE", "25", "50")
b <- list("2017", "FEMALE", "5", "100")
c <- list("2017", "MALE", "15", "75")
d <- list("2016", "MALE", "10", "35")
e <- list("2017", "FEMALE","55", "20")

data <- rbind(a,b,c,d,e)

#``````````````````````````````````````
## UI

library(shiny)

if(interactive()){

  ui = fluidPage(

    navbarPage("",

               #``````````````````````````````````````
               ## SHOES TAB

               tabPanel("SHOES", 

                        fluidRow(

                          column(2, "",
                                 selectInput("shoes_year", "YEAR", choices = c("2017", "2016")),
                                 selectInput("dataset", "CHOOSE POPULATION", choices = c("MALE", "FEMALE"))),

                          column(9, "SHOES"))),


               #``````````````````````````````````````
               ## HATS

               tabPanel("HATS",

                        fluidRow(

                          column(2, "",
                                 selectInput("hats_year", "YEAR", choices = c("2017", "2016")),
                                 selectInput("dataset", "CHOOSE POPULATION", choices     =c("MALE","FEMALE"))),

                          column(9, "HATS"))

               )))

  #``````````````````````````````````````

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input[["shoes_year"]],
                 {
                   updateSelectInput(session = session,
                                     inputId = "hats_year",
                                     selected = input[["shoes_year"]])
                 })

    observeEvent(input[["hats_year"]],
                 {
                   updateSelectInput(session = session,
                                     inputId = "shoes_year",
                                     selected = input[["hats_year"]])
                 })

  }

  #``````````````````````````````````````


  shinyApp(ui, server)
}

#``````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````

### ADDITIONAL STUFF (technical term)

Based on your comment of doing this on three or more tabs, I'm going to strongly recommend you stop what you're doing.  It's possible to do this through some clever `lapply`ing, such as

```
observeEvent(input$coat_year,
             {
               lapply(c("shoes_year", "hats_year"),
                      function(x) updateSelectInput(session = session,
                                                    inputId = x,
                                                    selected = input$coat_year))
             }
)
```

Which will minimize the amount of code you have to write, but you still need one of those blocks for each tab, and you will have to manually maintain the vector going into `lapply` to make sure it consists of all of appropriate controls.  Then you need to do it again for the data set.  There are other options, but I'm not sure they are any less work.

You're reaching a phase where your application is of sufficient complexity that you really ought to find ways to minimize the code work to make it easier to maintain. I present two options below which use only the tools made available in `shiny`.  The first uses `tabsetPanel`s instead of the `navbarPage`.  The second uses the `navbarPage` but embeds it in a `sidebarLayout`. There are many other solutions you could use if you explore the `shinyjs`, `shinydashboard`, and `shinyBS` packages, just to name a few.

#### tabsetPanel

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("year", "YEAR", choices = c("2017", "2016")),
          selectInput("dataset", "CHOOSE POPULATION", choices = c("MALE", "FEMALE"))
        ),

        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel(title = "Shoes",
                     uiOutput("shoe_input")),
            tabPanel(title = "Hats",
                     uiOutput("hat_input"))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),

  server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

    selected_input <- 
      reactive({
        tagList(
          h3(input$year),
          h3(input$dataset)
        )
      })

    output$shoe_input <- 
      renderUI({
        selected_input()
      })

    output$hat_input <- 
      renderUI({
        selected_input()
      })

  })

)
```

#### navbarPage

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(

  ui = shinyUI(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("year", "YEAR", choices = c("2017", "2016")),
        selectInput("dataset", "CHOOSE POPULATION", choices = c("MALE", "FEMALE"))
      ),

      mainPanel(
        navbarPage(
          title = "",
          tabPanel(title = "Shoes",
                   uiOutput("shoe_input")),
          tabPanel(title = "Hats",
                   uiOutput("hat_input"))
        )
      )
    )
  ),

  server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

    selected_input <- 
      reactive({
        tagList(
          h3(input$year),
          h3(input$dataset)
        )
      })

    output$shoe_input <- 
      renderUI({
        selected_input()
      })

    output$hat_input <- 
      renderUI({
        selected_input()
      })

  })

)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great.  I spent the last week trying to get something to work couldn’t so I really appreciate this!
My app uses navbarPage and I couldn’t get the sidebarLayout to work correctly – the formatting on tabs go real weird.  So I am just creating a column of custom inputs on each page. Then I couldn’t get the inputs to link up …. Looks like this code solve the issue.

Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I implemented the code and it works great.  I realized that I'm trying to link the selectInput in more than two tabs, is there any way that I can easily do this for three (or more tabs).  I posted new code above to show you what I'm trying to do.  Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way to do it for three or more tabs is to not do it.  See my additions.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin!  Again, this is very helpful.  I am going to use your tabsetPanel template to work from and I think it will do the trick (my code is getting out of hand and this will certainly help simplify).  Thank you again for taking the time to help me out - I really appreciate it!