# Update Shiny input to match other Shiny input: infinite loop

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I would like to have two instances of an input controller in my Shiny app, but I think that what I have to do instead is to have two inputs and update the value of each whenever the other changes. This way, they will appear to the user to be the same controls despite the fact that they have different IDs.

I anticipate being told to not do what I am trying to do, but the use case is that I have many tabs in a `dashboardPage()`, and only two of them share controls. Thus, putting the controls for those two pages in the sidebar would be confusing to the user.

I made a simple, working example of how to do this (using a dashboard to make it more clear why I want to do this) based on a [closely-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075333/selectinputupdate-in-r-selectinput-in-two-tabs-that-are-related) that was answered by convincing the asker to do something else (which worked in their case but not in mine). The app works fine except that as it gets more and more complex, the calculations take long enough sometimes that I can change one input and then change the other before the Shiny server has had time to update the values. This results in infinite feedback (input 1 updates to match input 2 while input 2 is updating to match input 1, and then this repeats for as long as I care to watch).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("chart-line")),
            menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("chart-line")),
            menuItem("Other Tab", tabName = "tab3", icon = icon("project-diagram"))
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            # First tab content
            tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
                # Input first number
                numericInput("input1", label = "Input 1", value = 1, min=1, step=1)
                ),
            # Second tab content
            tabItem(tabName = "tab2",
                # Input second number
                numericInput("input2", label = "Input 2", value = 1, min=1, step=1)
                ),
            # Third tab content
            tabItem(tabName = "tab3", "Unrelated content")
            )
        )
    )

server = function(input, output, session) {
    # Update inputs to match each other
    observeEvent(input$input1, {
        updateSelectInput(session = session,
                          inputId = "input2",
                          selected = input$input1)})
    observeEvent(input$input2, {
        updateSelectInput(session = session,
                          inputId = "input1",
                          selected = input$input2)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The question: what other ways are there to have separate pages with matching controls that control both pages but without having to put those controls on *every* page? Sub-question: is any of these methods going to avoid the infinite loop problem? Corollary: I saw an article that I think was rendering UI pages from auxiliary scripts and passing the input arguments to the URLs for those scripts, and that seemed like a great strategy, but I cannot find the article now and am struggling to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much simpler in fact. Instead of observing the numeric inputs, you can observe what tab is selected, and update a particular `numericInput` when the user arrives at that tab. So all we need is to provide an `id` for the `sidebarMenu` (`id = "tabs", ...`) and to observe the contents of this input variable:

```
observe({
    if (req(input$tabs) == "tab2") {
      updateSelectInput(...)
    }
  })
```

Changing input values with keyboard:
[image]

Changing input values with mouse clicking on up arrow:
[image]

Changing to tab2 while tab1 is rendering though the list of clicks:
[image]

---

Updated code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("chart-line")),
      menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("chart-line")),
      menuItem("Other Tab", tabName = "tab3", icon = icon("project-diagram"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
              # Input first number
              numericInput("input1", label = "Input 1", value = 1000, min=1, step=1),
              plotOutput("plot1")
      ),
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "tab2",
              # Input second number
              numericInput("input2", label = "Input 2", value = 1000, min=1, step=1),
              plotOutput("plot2")
      ),
      # Third tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "tab3", "Unrelated content")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  # some (not so) long computation
  long_comp1 <- reactive({
    x <- sample(input$input1, size=10000000, replace = TRUE)
    y <- sample(input$input1, size=10000000, replace = TRUE)
    m <- matrix(x, nrow = 500, ncol=200)
    n <- matrix(y, nrow = 200, ncol=500)
    p <- n %*% m  
    p
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    hist(long_comp1(), main = paste("input1 is", input$input1))
  })

  # some (not so) long computation
  long_comp2 <- reactive({
    x <- sample(input$input2, size=10000000, replace = TRUE)
    y <- sample(input$input2, size=10000000, replace = TRUE)
    m <- matrix(x, nrow = 500, ncol=200)
    n <- matrix(y, nrow = 200, ncol=500)
    p <- n %*% m  
    p
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    hist(long_comp2(), main = paste("input2 is", input$input2))
  })

  # Update inputs to match each other
  observe({
    if (req(input$tabs) == "tab2") {
      updateSelectInput(session = session,
                        inputId = "input2",
                        selected = input$input1)
    }
  })

  observe({
    if (req(input$tabs) == "tab1") {
      updateSelectInput(session = session,
                        inputId = "input1",
                        selected = input$input2)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think the idea sounds great, but I was still able to get your implementation to produce the infinite feedback problem . Reproduce: Run the application. On Tab 1, push the up button on the numeric input many times (4 was enough for my computer). Switch to Tab 2 immediately.

Comment: Have a look at the edit. Observing tabs instead of numeric inputs appears to solve it.

Comment: Good thought for an alternate strategy, but I can still reproduce the bug. The behavior is modified slightly. Now, switching to the second tab in the middle of calculations makes the value of the input jump back and forth between its initial value and the last value chosen in the first tab (the same happens when switching back to the first tab afterward). This happens even if I make sure that the histograms with initial values have finished loading for both tabs before messing with the inputs. Rather than typing in the input, try the arrows to step up or down a few times.

Comment: Not sure what you are seeing, but there is no infinite loop on my end. When you click the up arrow in the `numericInput` 5 times you are effectively changing `input$input1` five times, so the plotting code, being dependent on `input$input1` will execute 5 times and the plot will refresh for each value between no clicks and five clicks. After its done, however, there is no more looping through those 5 values, which I think was the original problem. Check the new gif in the answer above to see the behavior on my end.

Comment: I am talking about what happens if you change tabs before the execution is done.

Comment: See another gif. On my end there is no jumping back and forth when switching to the second tab.

Comment: I am no longer able to reproduce the problem with this code, so I guess you were right (I do not know what happened before). I am not quite sure why this works, though. Wouldn't we expect the same behavior out of this as we got out of updating when the other input changed? I do not see why basing the observe on the tab should be different. Or is the difference primarily in `observe()` versus `observeEvent()`?

Comment: We are updating the inputs **only when changing to a new tab**. Before, the updates were dependent on the inputs. So, you can wait for the computation to finish before changing `input$input2`, but once `input$input2` gets a new value, that triggers updating `input$input1` (because they are co-dependent). By monitoring tabs, you avoid this codependency. From the user's perspective, the change with the most-recent time stamp will always be the one the user made _before_ switching tabs. So the new tab inherits the _last input value_ from the previous tab, where the user just made the change.